# Парсер data атрибутов с сайта

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

пишу небольшой парсер на python, однако наткнулся на одну проблемку, суть вот в чём:

Информация хранится вот так:

`<div class="right-panel form-viewport"
data-description="description" 
data-editable="false" 
data-errors="" 
data-id="206" 
data-industry-id="383" 
data-industry-name="Marketing and Advertising" 
data-name="name" 
data-website-url="link" 
id="company_fields"></div>`

Мой код выглядит сейчас вот так:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

max_page = 18
pages = []

for x in range(17, max_page + 1):
    pages.append(requests.get('https://link.com/companies/' + str(x)))

for r in pages:
    html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')

    for el in html.select('.panel-body'):
        title = el.select('.panel-body > .right-part')
        print(title)
```

Выводит всё это вот так:

```
[]
[]
[<div class="right-part">
<div class="right-panel form-viewport" 
data-description='description' 
data-editable="false" 
data-errors="" 
data-id="18" 
data-industry-id="383" 
data-industry-name="Marketing and Advertising" 
data-name="T3leads" 
data-website-url="link" 
id="company_fields">
</div>]
[]
[]
```

Ну и так далее. Вопрос заключается в том, как достать значение сразу из data атрибутов, а не отчищать потом текст от тегов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Атрибуты достаются как из словаря через `tag['value']`

Попробуйте

```
title[0]['data-industry-name']
```

Через get в Вашем случае тк селектор не всегда выдает то что нужно:

```
title[0].get('data-industry-name')
```

Comment: ```  File "main.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(title[0].get('data-industry-name'))
IndexError: list index out of range
````

Comment: без [0] попробуй. в элемент надо вытащить тот самый див

Comment: добавьте в вопрос полностью страничку чтоб можно было переписать селектор. а то в примере у вас 2 дива в одном элементе, один из них не закрытый...

Comment: Вот от сюда беру: https://mymediads.com/companies/17