# Парсинг страницы html в Python

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

Подскажите как вытащить значение атрибута 'value' наружу, используя `BeautifulSoup`. С помощью:

```py
delivery_data = soup.find('fieldset', class_="form-fieldset")
data = delivery_data.find_all('div')
print(data[0].find_all('div')[2])
```

Я извлекаю следующее:

```html
<div class="form-group">
<label>Imię i nazwisko / nazwa firmy</label>
<div class="form-field"><input id="order_customer_delivery_full_name" 
name="order[customer_delivery_full_name]" type="text" value="Alina Rol"/></div>
</div>
```

Но как дальше извлечь значение атрибута 'value' не знаю.

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1097324/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80-data-%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Парсер data атрибутов с сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1097324/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80-data-%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сразу извлечь значение атрибута, благо оно находится в элементе с `id`:

```py
value = soup.select_one('#order_customer_delivery_full_name')['value']
```

Тест:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

root = BeautifulSoup("""
<div class="form-field"><input id="order_customer_delivery_full_name" 
name="order[customer_delivery_full_name]" type="text" value="Alina Rol"/></div>
</div>
""", 'html.parser')

print(root.select_one('#order_customer_delivery_full_name')['value'])
# Alina Rol
```

Comment: спасибо большое, мне очень помогло ))